# Kivy - Background App doesn't work properly after screen gets turned off

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I created an app for android devices to read sensor data (accelerometer, compass and gyroscope) as fast as possible.

However, it works already as a background app such that it I can get out of the app and it still reads the sensors. When the screen turns off (either by time or manually) the app stops saving the read sensor data.

If you can help me in any way I would appreciate it very much.

Here is my code --> main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder    
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from android import AndroidService

import atexit

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:           
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'Pictures/background_3.jpeg'
    orientation: 'vertical' 

    Label:  
        id: time_label          

    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: self.width/24
        text: ' '

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
#        spacing: '30dp'
        Button:
            font_size: self.height/2
            id: toggle_button
            text: 'Start'
            on_press: app.start_measuring() 
            background_color: (0.1,0.2,0.79,1)       
        Button:
            font_size: self.height/2
            id: toggle_button
            text: 'Stop'
            on_press: app.stop_measuring() 
            background_color: (0.1,0.2,0.79,1)     
        Button:
            id: clear_button
            font_size: self.height/2
            text: 'Delete Data'
            on_press: app.ask_for_deletion()
            background_color: (0.8,0.1,0.1,1)            
'''

def exit_handler():
    if not out_file.closed:
        out_file.close()  

class AirApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        self.service = None                  
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.root

    def start_measuring(self):                    
        self.root.ids.label.text = "Measuring ..." 
        service = AndroidService('AirApp', 'measuring')
        service.start('service started')
        self.service = service                      

    def stop_measuring(self):        
        self.root.ids.label.text = "Measurement stopped"
        if self.service: 
            self.service.stop()
            self.service = None

    def do_deletion(self,event):          #deletes file
        self.root.ids.label.text = "Measured data deleted"
        self.popup.dismiss()
        if self.service: 
            self.service.stop()
            self.service = None
        out_file = open("/sdcard/sensor_data.txt", "r+")
        out_file.truncate()
        out_file.close()       

    def ask_for_deletion(self):          #popup asking for intention 
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        content_cancel = Button(text='No', font_size = self.root.width/18)
        content_accept = Button(text='Yes', font_size = self.root.width/18)
        box.add_widget(Label(text='Are you sure that you want\nto delete all data irrevocably?', font_size = self.root.width/18))
        box.add_widget(content_cancel)
        box.add_widget(content_accept)
        self.popup = Popup(title='Delete data?', title_size = self.root.width/14, 
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(self.root.width*3/4, self.root.height*6/7),
                      content=box)                     
        content_cancel.bind(on_release=self.popup.dismiss)
        content_accept.bind(on_release=self.do_deletion)                       
        self.popup.open()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass      

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    out_file = open("/sdcard/sensor_data.txt","a")
    out_file.close()
    atexit.register(exit_handler)       #if app gets forced to close: close file 
    AirApp().run()
```

And here in the service folder is the other (background script) main.py:

```
from plyer import accelerometer
from plyer import compass
from plyer import gyroscope
from plyer import gps

import atexit
import time

def exit_handler():
    accelerometer.disable()
    compass.disable()
    gyroscope.disable() 
    try:
        gps.stop()
    except NotImplementedError:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()

def measure():
    out_file = open("/sdcard/sensor_data.txt","a")
    val_acceleration = accelerometer.acceleration
    val_compass = compass.orientation
    val_gyroscope = gyroscope.orientation
    try:
        safe_string = "Ax " + str(val_acceleration[0]) + "\n" + "Ay " + str(val_acceleration[1]) + "\n" + "Az " + str(val_acceleration[2]) + "\n"            
    except:
        safe_string = 'Ax 0.0\nAy 0.0\nAz 0.0\n'        
    out_file.write(safe_string)        

    try:
        safe_string = "Cx " + str(val_compass[0]) + "\n" + "Cy " + str(val_compass[1]) + "\n" + "Cz " + str(val_compass[2]) + "\n"            
    except:
        safe_string = 'Cx 0.0\nCy 0.0\nCz 0.0\n'
    out_file.write(safe_string)

    try:
        safe_string = "Gyx " + str(val_gyroscope[0]) + "\n" + "Gyy " + str(val_gyroscope[1]) + "\n" + "Gyz " + str(val_gyroscope[2]) + "\n"            
    except:
        safe_string = 'Gyx 0.0\nGyy 0.0\nGyz 0.0\n'            
    out_file.write(safe_string)    
    out_file.write("T1 " + str(long(time.time()*10**6)) + 'e-6\n\n')    # in seconds; for evaluation: *10**(-6)
    out_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    accelerometer.enable()
    compass.enable()
    gyroscope.enable()  
    atexit.register(exit_handler)       #if app gets forced to close: close file  
    while True:
        measure()    

    accelerometer.disable()
    compass.disable()
    gyroscope.disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

use kivy service, to run the operation in the background

https://blog.kivy.org/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/

Comment: Gilbert Wamichwe, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).